# Parsing non-mutually-exclusive groups of command-line arguments

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to find a way of parsing sequences of related arguments, preferably using `argparse`.

For example:

```
command --global-arg --subgroup1 --arg1 --arg2 --subgroup2 --arg1 --arg3 --subgroup3 --arg4 --subcommand1 --arg1 --arg3
```

where `--global-arg` applies to the whole command, but each `--subgroupN` argument has sub-arguments that apply only to it (and may have the same name, such as `--arg1` and `--arg3` above), and where some sub-arguments are optional, so the number of sub-arguments is not constant. However, I know that each `--subgroupN` sub-argument set is complete either by the presence of another `--subgroupN` or the end of the argument list (I am not fussed if global arguments cannot appear at the end, although I imagine that is possible as long as they don't clash with sub-argument names).

The `--subgroupN` elements are essentially sub-commands, but I do not appear to be able to use the sub-parser ability of `argparse` as it slurps any following `--subgroupN` entries as well (and therefore barfs with unexpected arguments).

(An example of this style of argument list is used by xmlstarlet)

Are there any suggestions beyond writing my own parser? I assume I can at least leverage something out of argparse if that is the only option...

## Examples

The examples below were an attempt to find a way to parse an argument structure along the following lines:

```
(a --name <name>|b --name <name>)+
```

in the first example I hoped to have --a and --b introduce a set of arguments that were processed by a subparser.

I was hoping to get something out perhaps along the lines of

```
Namespace(a=Namespace(name="dummya"), b=Namespace(name="dummyb"))
```

## subparser example fails

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser("a")
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser("b")
parser_a.add_argument("--name")
parser_b.add_argument("--name")
parser.parse_args(["a", "--name", "dummy"])
> Namespace(name='dummy') (Good)
parser.parse_args(["b", "--name", "dummyb", "a", "--name", "dummya"])
> error: unrecognized arguments: a (BAD)
```

## mutually exclusive group fails

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g1 = g.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g1.add_argument("--name")
g2 = g.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g2.add_argument("--name")
> ArgumentError: argument --name: conflicting option string(s): --name (BAD)
```

(I wasn't really expecting this to work, it was an attempt to see if I could have repetition of grouped arguments.)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you tried. You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: There is at least one earlier SO question about handling multiple subcommands.  Solutions involve things like recursive subcommands.  None are straight forward uses of `argparse`.

Comment: Searching for `[argparse] multiple` turned up posts like this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/25318622/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the subparser mechanism, `argparse` is not designed to handle groups of arguments.  Other than the `nargs` grouping, it handles the arguments in the order that they appear in the `argv` list.

As I mentioned in the comments there have been earlier questions, which can probably be found by search with words like `multiple`.  But one way or other they seek to work about the basic order-independent design of `argparse`.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A901925+[argparse]+multiple

I think the most straight forward solution is to process the `sys.argv` list before hand, breaking it into groups, and then passing those sublists to one or more `parsers`.

```
parse [command --global-arg], 
parse [--subgroup1 --arg1 --arg2], 
parse [--subgroup2 --arg1 --arg3], 
parse [--subgroup3 --arg4], 
parse [--subcommand1 --arg1 --arg3]
```

In fact the only alternative is to use that subparser 'slurp everything else' behavior to get a remainder of arguments that can be parsed again.  Use `parse_known_args` to return a list of unknown arguments (`parse_args` raises an error if that list is not empty).

Comment: OK - that sounds something along the lines of what I expected. I'll dig through the previous comments (hadn't found anything obvious when I searched earlier), but at least I know I was thinking along the right sort of lines!

Answer (score 0):

Using [hpaulj's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34930469/2098827) above, I came up with the following:

```
args = [
    "--a", "--name", "dummya", 
    "--b", "--name", "dummyb",
    "--a", "--name", "another_a", "--opt"
]
parser_globals = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser_globals.add_argument("--test")

parser_a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser_a.add_argument("--name")
parser_a.add_argument("--opt", action="store_true")

parser_b = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser_b.add_argument("--name")

command_parsers = {
    "--a": parser_a,
    "--b": parser_b
}

the_namespace = argparse.Namespace()
if globals is not None:
    (the_namespace, rest) = parser_globals.parse_known_args(args)

subcommand_dict = vars(the_namespace)
subcommand = []
val = rest.pop()
while val:
    if val in command_parsers:
        the_args = command_parsers[val].parse_args(subcommand)
        if val in subcommand_dict:
            if "list" is not type(subcommand_dict[val]):
                subcommand_dict[val] = [subcommand_dict[val]]
            subcommand_dict[val].append(the_args)
        else:
            subcommand_dict[val] = the_args
        subcommand = []
    else:
        subcommand.insert(0, val)
    val = None if not rest else rest.pop()
```

I end up with:

```
Namespace(
    --a=[
        Namespace(
            name='another_a',
            opt=True
        ),
        Namespace(
            name='dummya',
            opt=False
        )
    ],
    --b=Namespace(
        name='dummyb'
    ),
    test=None
)
```

which seems to serve my purposes.